# Pass dynamic controller in route in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

```
Route::get($PageController[2], [RollsController::class , $PageController[2]]);
```

Hi coder, I want to pass dynamic class instead of `RollsController`.

Suppose that I have `$controller_name = 'RollsController';`
So I want to pass this variable in route instead of `RollsController::class`

How to achieve them?

I tried like following, but it gives me an error. Thanks in advance.

```
Route::get($PageController[2], [$controller_name::class , $PageController[2]]); //I want this type of route with dynamic controller.
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... what error?

Comment: when i write this code ----> 
Route::get($PageController[2], [$PageController[2]::class , $PageController[2]])->name('pages.' . $PageController[2]);

and it give error like this
  Whoops\Exception\ErrorException

  Cannot use ::class with dynamic class name

Comment: what about this is actually dynamic btw? and you would just have the full classname in the variable `$controller_name` already (as a string)

Comment: `$urls = Menu::all()->toArray();
    if (!empty($urls) && is_array($urls)) {
    foreach ($urls as $key => $value) {
    $PageController = explode('/', $value['PageUrl']);
    if ($PageController[2] != "") {
    $classname = $PageController[2].'Controller';
    Route::get($PageController[2], [$classname::class , $PageController[2]])->name('pages.' . $PageController[2]);
    }
    }
    }
    `
    this is my code and i want acheive like this

Comment: `$classname` is a string containing the classname, not an object ... you should edit your question and add your code to it in a codeblock

Comment: so how we convert into object ?

Comment: you don't as you already have the string ... `$object::class` or `Something::class` returns a string; you already have the string

Answer (score 1):

You can use `::class` only on object

```
$controller_name = RollsController::class;
Route::get($PageController[2], [(new $controller_name)::class, $PageController[2]]);
```

or using reflection

```
$controller_name = RollsController::class;
try {
    $oClass = new ReflectionClass($controller_name);
    Route::get($PageController[2], [$oClass::class, $PageController[2]]);
} catch (ReflectionException $e) {
}
```

Comment: its not working, how we can pass controller from database to route , i tried but it give me error `` $urls = Menu::all()->toArray();

if (!empty($urls) && is_array($urls)) {
    foreach ($urls as $key => $value) {
        $PageController = explode('/', $value['PageUrl']);
        if ($PageController[2] != "") {
            $controller_name =  $PageController[2];
                Route::get($PageController[2], [$controller_name .'::class', $PageController[2]])->name('pages.' . $PageController[2]);
           
          
        }
    }
} ``

Comment: its not the question you asked for. The question was how to pass class controller from a variable with the class